# How to simplify a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops

I have this piece of Python code that fills up a 2d matrix in a for loop

```
img=zeros((len(bins_x),len(bins_y)))

for i in arange(0,len(ix)):
   img[ix[i]][iy[i]]=dummy[i]
```

Is it possible to use a vectorial operation for the last two lines of code? Is there also something that might speed up the calculation?

Comment: Can you post some sample contents of ix, iy, dummy, bins_x, bins_y?

Comment: This is not really an answer (that's why it's a comment) but while someone comes up with something more "decent", you may want to take a look to the itertools module (http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) See if there's something interesting for you there **:)**

Comment: as far as speeding it up, `img[ix[i], iy[i] ] = dummy[i]` is likely to be faster as it only need to do indexing once instead of twice.  Also note that you can pretty this up a little by `for x,y,z in zip(ix,iy,dummy): img[x,y] = z`, but I don't know if that will be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ix, iy are index sequences:

```
img[ix, iy] = dummy
```

Comment: I just discovered this about 3 seconds ago. (+1)

Comment: Although, technically, you might want to slice them in case they're not the same length:  `img[ix, iy[:len(ix)] ] = dummy[:len(ix)]`

Comment: As @mgilson pointed out, you may want to make sure that `ix`, `iy` and `dummy` have all the same size beforehand...

Comment: Is this possible with python 2.7? I keep getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`.

Comment: @Kevin: the OP likely uses numpy.zeros() function that returns a numpy array that supports `ix,iy` indexing.

Comment: @mgilson: yes, the slicing might emulate the specific example in the question more literally. If I understand the OP's intent correctly then it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/). In particular, the [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method might be useful. Here is an example (adapted from the second link):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> np.reshape(a, (3,2))
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```